# Run a .exe console application using cronjob in linux

Tags: cron, console, mono

i am trying to schedule a console application (.exe) using cronjob . The command i am trying to schedule is

21 18 * * * /home/vijayk/test/loyalty/loyalty_build/ mono AirArabia.exe

but my exe is not getting triggered .

How i can run this file using cron job - any suggestions please...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the mono command is incorrect. It should be:

`mono /home/vijayk/test/loyalty/loyalty_build/AirArabia.exe`

If it still doesn't work, I would suggest making a shell script to run your program, and make cron call that shell script.